# Split excel row values into multiple rows when specific column value has comma in python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a Excel data with 5 columns and one of the column(say column 5th) has multiple values with comma separated(Say column 5th first row has values "A,B,C"). I would to check each rows in excel and write a separate entry for each values in excel file using openpyxl(expected output would be, 3 rows in excel now and column 5th 1st row value = A, column 5th 2nd row value = B, etc).

Comment: copy 10 rows of your excel and paste it here or reproduce a sample which mimics your issue, please also post your intended output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?